# Perl use of unitialized value

Tags: perl, debugging

I'm new at Perl and need some help debugging.
Here is my current code (lines of Data at bottom redacted for privacy):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Address;

my %matches;
my $records = 0;
my $recipient = "";
while (<DATA>) {
    foreach my $addr (Email::Address->parse($_)) {
        my @fields = split /\s/, $_;
        $records = $fields[12];
        $recipient = $addr->address;
        $matches{'$recipient'} += $records;
    }
}
foreach my $rfc822 (keys %matches) {
    print $matches{'$rfc822'}, " ", $rfc822, "\n";
}

__DATA__
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\redacted>C:\Perl\test4.pl
Use of uninitialized value in print at C:\Perl\test4.pl line 18, <DATA> line 4.
$recipient
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for days, thanks!!

Comment: variables do not interpolate in single quotes, I believe you meant `$matches{"$rfc822"}`. However since `$rfc822` is a variable, you can leave off the quotes entirely: `$matches{$rfc822}`

Comment: If you need to withhold sensitive information from your post, it's always best to substitute something imagined that generates the same issue. The easier you make it for us to reproduce the problem you're having, the better quality answer you will get.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error has already been explained: you have used a variable name in single quotes as a hash key in two places

Here are some more notes on your program

- There's no tax on whitespace, so you should use it liberally to indent your statements and leave blank lines so as to make your code more easy to read and debug. It is only polite to lay out your code neatly when you are asking for help with it even if you don't want to do it for yourself
- Variables should be declared as *late* as possible, preferably at the point they are first used. In this case the only variable that needs to be declared globally is `%matches` because it needs to persist across iterations of the following `for` loop. Everything else can be declared within the loop when it is defined
- `for` and `foreach` are identical in function, so it is usually best to use the shorter of the two
- Whenever you're tempted to write `split /\s+/`, you almost certainly mean `split ' '` which is pretty much identical except that it doesn't return an empty string for the first field if the string being split begins with whitespace. (It is different from `split / /` which splits on individual spaces.) The default parameters for `split` are `split ' ', $_`, so you can use just `split` here
- It is much neater to use interpolation to build strings consisting of variable values and string constants. `$matches{$rfc822}, " ", $rfc822, "\n"` is very much more readable written as `"$matches{$rfc822} $rfc822\n"`

Here is your code with the errors fixed and my points taken into account

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Address;

my %matches;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    for my $addr ( Email::Address->parse($_) ) {
        my @fields    = split;
        my $records   = $fields[12];
        my $recipient = $addr->address;
        $matches{$recipient} += $records;
    }
}

for my $rfc822 ( keys %matches ) {
    print "$matches{$rfc822} $rfc822\n";
}

__DATA__
```

Comment: thanks! I greatly appreciate the help, I'm very new at this so I will definitely take all your advice into account

Answer (score 1):

Like @HunterMcMillen said you do not need the quotes around your variables when assigning to a hash. So update the following portions of your code like so.

```
...
$matches{$recipient} += $records;
}
}
foreach my $rfc822 (keys %matches) {
print $matches{$rfc822}, " ", $rfc822, "\n";
}
```